# what does 'proc' in 'sigprocmask' mean?

Tags: linux, c, signals

I'm new to Linux and signals, sorry if my question sounds dumb, we know that Applications can explicitly block and unblock selected signals using the `sigprocmask` function, but what does 'proc' stand for?

Comment: Please try the man pages as a first resort. Also note the system call interfaces for signals are very unforgiving: using the library functions will save you all kinds of trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `proc` in `sigprocmask()` is short for "process", it's the "process signal mask" (see, for example, https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Signal-Mask.html).

Quoting from the reference above:

> Note that you must not use `sigprocmask` in multi-threaded processes, because each thread has its own signal mask and there is no single process signal mask. According to POSIX, the behavior of `sigprocmask` in a multi-threaded process is "unspecified". Instead, use `pthread_sigmask`.

Comment: Surely a syscall to be avoided. The man page contains two conflicting sentences. (A) sigprocmask() is used to fetch and/or change the signal mask of the calling *thread*. (so not actually a *process*). (B) The  use  of sigprocmask() is unspecified in a multithreaded process; see pthread_sigmask(3).